# How to send Ctrl-C to dotMemory command line CLI when it runs in background with supervisord?

Tags: .net, supervisord, dotmemory

I have multiple .NET Core programs running in a Ubuntu background using supervisord (see below). That supervisord.conf is located in the Hello-World folder.

```
[program:hello-world-1]
command = /all-hello-worlds/dotMemory-Cli-Linux/tools/dotMemory.sh start-net-core --service-input=null --trigger-max-snapshots=5 --trigger-delay=2m --trigger-timer=00:01:00 Hello-World-1.dll
directory = /all-hello-worlds/Hello-World-1
autostart = true
autorestart = unexpected
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

In each supervisord.conf, I use:
`dotMemory.sh start-net-core --trigger-delay=1m --trigger-timer=00:00:10 ./HelloWorld.dll`

When the supervisord runs the .NET Core programs in the background, I could see the dotMemory printing message saying about "Press Ctrl+C to end the profiling"

Those .NET Core programmes are bundled in a Dorker container, which runs `/usr/bin/supervisord -c /all-hello-worlds/supervisord.conf`

Here is another supervisord.conf called `supervisord.conf` which is located in the `all-hello-worlds` folder

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
nodaemon = true   ; run in the background aka daemonizing

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.
[include]
files = /all-hello-worlds/*/supervisord.conf
```

You can visualise the folder structure in Ubuntu as followed:

```
all-hello-worlds (root folder)
| --- dotMemory-Cli-Linux
| --- supervisord.conf
| --- Hello-World-1
   | --- Hello-World-1.dll
   | --- supervisord.conf
| --- Hello-World-2
   | --- Hello-World-2.dll
   | --- supervisord.conf
```

Now I struggle sending Ctrl-C command to supervisord Hello-World processes. If I use `supervisorctl stop Hello-World-1`, the dotMemory does not save the DMW file properly & I need to use `dotMemory recover` method to get the DMW file (which is troublesome)

If I use `kill -SIGINT [dotMemory process ID]`, the supervisord restarts the process & does not save the DMW file properly.

Is there anyway to send Ctrl-C command to dotMemory running in the background with supervisord?
I have attached 2 supervisord.conf files here.

Let me know if you need more information from me.
Thanks.

Comment: If for some reason the dotMemory actually expects the control character instead of a SIGINT you could try to `echo '\x3' > /proc/{pid}/fd/0`. Normally this wouldn't work as processes expect a SIGINT and ignore the control character.

Comment: Edit: Forgot the `-e` switch in the echo command.

However I made a quick test with a dotnet application and it does not seem to trigger the `Console.ReadKey`.

Comment: @MrPaulch, did you mean `echo '\x3' > /proc/{pid}/fd/0` or `echo -e '\x3' > /proc/{pid}/fd/0`?

Comment: If Anna's post answer you question, please accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an old dotMemory console version which runs via mono. `kill -SIGINT [dotMemory process ID]` command doesn't work properly with it.

However, `##dotMemory["disconnect"]` can be sent to stdin via file:

- Modify command line with `--service-input` argument:

`dotMemory.sh start-net-core --service-input=<Path to service messages file>/dotMemoryInput.txt`

- At the moment when you want to stop profiling session, edit the file:

`echo '##dotMemory["disconnect"]' >> <Path to service messages file>/dotMemoryInput.txt`

Profiling session will be finished and workspace will be saved in this case.

The other way is to update dotMemory clt version to 2021.1.5. Since 2021.1 dotMemory runs via dotnet and `kill -SIGINT [dotMemory process ID]` works properly with this version, workspace is saved successfully.